# drawRect, drawing items and ignoring the mask

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, drawrect

Hello I am trying to create a graph in `drawRect`. Currently the graph looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the text "Today" is being cut off by the gradient mask. I create the mask like so:

```
        // Gradient Fill
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        let colors = [gradStartColor.cgColor, gradEndColor.cgColor] as CFArray
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let colorLocations: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]
        let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorSpace, colors: colors, locations: colorLocations)!
        let startPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: maxY(rect: rect))
        let endPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: height)
        let clippingPath: UIBezierPath = linePath.copy() as! UIBezierPath
        clippingPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: coords[coords.count - 1].x, y: height))
        clippingPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: coords[0].x, y: height))
        clippingPath.close()
        clippingPath.addClip()
        context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: startPoint, end: endPoint, options: [])
```

My question is how can I then draw items on top of the graph whilst ignoring the mask so they aren't cut off?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the current graphics state before the clipping operation and restore it afterwards, so that the clipping is no longer active.

```
context.saveGState()
//do clipped drawing
context.restoreGState()
//do further drawing
```